# How can I hotkey an allied unit?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to be able to hotkey an allied unit, like a scouting worker, so I can instantly jump to it by double-tapping the hotkey. The usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you have shared control you cannot hotkey allied units as they don't "belong" to you and you have no influence over their actions.